# Java - Create directories and upload files through proxy server to main server(destination)

Tags: java

I'm very curious to know if Java supports the make directory and upload features/protocols when going through a Proxy Server? I'm asking because, I'm soon to learn a bit of Java just to see if it's possible, since C# .NET does not support these protocols when going through a Proxy Server. If so, could you please point me in the right direction & maybe provide the best libraries(Free) to use. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: What are "these protocols" of which you speak? The premise of your question is broken, I'm afraid. I'm sure any C# FTP library supports `mkdir`, proxy server or not; but an HTTP library would not, regardless of language, since HTTP doesn't offer such a facilty. Of course if you have server-side code to create a directory -- say, as a web service -- then any web services client library could be used to invoke it.

Comment: Hi Ernest..Thanks for the response. Sorry...To clarify. If using a FTP proxy class in Java, I'm hoping that it supported methods (mkdir and upload) when going through a Proxy Server. In C#, I'll get something like "FTP commands not supported when using HTTP Proxy". Unfortunately, I do not have server-side code. I just have to get to it...create directories and upload files within those directories. My code works fine except for when a Proxy Server is thrown in the mix. Microsoft said they will not support mkdir & upload when going through a proxy. Thanks Ernest.

Comment: Is [this](http://mycodetrip.com/2008/10/29/fix-for-error-the-requested-ftp-command-is-not-supported-when-using-http-proxy_118/) helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment on C#, but Java surely has very good support for proxies.

You can read [the Oracle documentation on Using Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html). Also please go through the [ProxySelector](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) which was introduced in JDK 1.5.

After you set the system properties you can use system proxies in the following way. An example is given under..

```
Proxy proxy = (Proxy) ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://www.yahoo.com/")).iterator().
      next();
System.out.println("proxy hostname : " + proxy.type());
InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress)
proxy.address();
if (addr == null) {
   System.out.println("No Proxy");
}
else {
   System.out.println("proxy hostname : " 
   + addr.getHostName());
   System.out.println("proxy port : "
   + addr.getPort());
}
```

Comment: Awesome.....Thanks AurA. Any particular program you would suggest I use? Just be certain...let's say I use the code snippet you so graciously provided me...Could I then use FTP methods like make directory and upload?

Comment: use to one given in Oracle website.... my first link... what i gave was just a simple example.